# Why is smart cast so prominently highlighted?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, syntax-highlighting

I try to understand why smart casts are so prominently highlighted in IntelliJ. For example this String? gets smart casted to String and it draws a lot of attention:
[image: smart cast example]

I'm not looking for an explanation of the smart cast feature in general, but rather try understand why Jetbrains thinks this needs developer attention.

Comment: I get why this is downvoted and/or closed. I was unsure if SO is the right place to ask this question, but there has to be some reasoning behind it. The highlighting is so odd, nothing in Java or Kotlin looks like this (with IntelliJ default settings)

Comment: Funny - I've been using IntelliJ with Kotlin for quite a while but it never drew my attention. Thanks for bringing this to my attention - but I don't think it stands out very much. Especially since it turns gray once the cursor is inside the green section.

Answer (score 0):

Not JetBrains, but... Because the type change due to a smart cast is a very non-obvious thing that happens in your code, and there's no real way that you yourself could explicitly make it more visible. So the syntax highlighting does it for you.

Comment: Hmmm, but why not highlight things like autoboxing then in a similar fashion?

Comment: For one, there's only so many things you can highlight. And autoboxing is a JVM specific matter, and 99% of the time only a concern for optimization. Getting a smart cast on a variable is an essential feature of Kotlin regardless of platform, and a matter of whether your code compiles or not.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say from JetBrains perspective, but my opinion is because you have declared that variable first as String? for example, now one would have expected that it keeps it type but instead type is changed to String using smart cast, in this case its simple, but sometimes you might have bigger hierarchy of sealed classes for example, where different classes have different methods and this should help you remembering that type isn't same as declared, this is maybe their way to say it used to be X type, but now it is Y inside this context.